# See Google Autocomplete Address with nuxtJs separately

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

I am using Google Autocomplete Places with NuxtJs like described in the followed link:

https://medium.com/@jpoechill/superbasic-google-autocomplete-with-nuxt-js-378a9262659a

Its working properly but the fact is that I want to get the data from the address separately in autofill inputs like this "Autofill fields":

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-place-autocomplete

I dont want anything elaborated, if I could return the address separately (by country, state, city,...) in console it would be great!

Here follows the code:

```
<v-text-field id="searchTextField" v-model="searchTextField" label="Digite um endereço" v-on:keydown="searchAddress()" color="rgba(65, 27, 153, 0.95)" outlined>
</v-text-field>
```

Method:

```
async searchAddress() {
       var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
         new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var options = {
          bounds: defaultBounds,
          types: ['address']
        };
        this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          input, options
        );
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following code:

```
  async searchAddress() {
    
    var address1Field = document.querySelector("#searchTextField");
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address1Field, {
      componentRestrictions: { },
      fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
      types: ["address"],
    });
    address1Field.focus();
    this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", this.fillInAddress);
  },



  fillInAddress() {
    this.place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.selectedAddress = this.place.address_components
    console.log(this.selectedAddress)
  }
```

And the variables:

```
place: "",
selectedAddress: "",
autocomplete: "",
```